# Sort numeric data.table values that are formatted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to create my table.

Find below my minimum viable example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  function loadHardware() {
    var results = {
      "profRigHardware": [{
          "title": "Product1",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product1/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product1.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "165.99",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product2",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product2/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product2.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "161.99",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product3",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product3/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product3.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-6.06",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product4",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-19.2",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product5",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product4/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product4.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-116.06",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product6",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-0.06",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product7",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-18.24",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product8",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "75.68",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product9",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "863.31",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product10",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "20.1",
        }
      ]
    };
    const rentabilityHtml = function(daily_netProfit) {
      if (daily_netProfit < 0) {
        return `<div style="color:red;"><b>$${daily_netProfit}/day</b></div>`
      } else {
        return `<div style="color:green;"><b>$${daily_netProfit}/day</b></div>`
      }
    }
    //transform data set
    let dataSet = results.profRigHardware.map((item, i) => [
      `<img src="${ item.smallImg }" alt="${ item.title }" height="42" width="42"> 
         <a href="${item.permalink}" target="_blank">
            ${item.title}
             </a>`,
      parseFloat(item.daily_netProfit),
    ])

    $('#allHardwareOverview').DataTable({
      data: dataSet,
      destroy: true,
      iDisplayLength: 25,
      responsive: true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "order": [
        [1, 'desc']
      ],
      columns: [{
          title: "Model"
        },
        {
          title: "Profitability",
          render: function(profit) {
            return rentabilityHtml(parseFloat(profit))
          }
        }
      ],
      "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $('#datatablediv').css('opacity', 1);
      }
    });
  }
  loadHardware();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
  <div class="table-responsive overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="allHardwareOverview" style="width:100%; float: left;" class="table table-bordered"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to order my values the following way:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| Model     | Profitability |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product9  | $863.31/day   |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product1  | $165.99/day   |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product2  | $161.99/day   |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product8  | $75.68/day    |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product10 | $20.1/day     |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product6  | $-0.06/day    |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product3  | $-6.06/day    |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product7  | $-18.24/day   |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product4  | $-19.2/day    |
+-----------+---------------+
| Product5  | $-116.06/day  |
+-----------+---------------+
```

As you can see the current order is wrongly shown.

I tried to `parseFloat(profit)` before formatting it, however I still get the wrong order?

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: parseFloat(profit) will return NaN parseFloat(string) will return a floating number if the string is a number or the first part of the string starts with a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the **render()** method you can check the mode type using **render(data, type)**, and based on this mode type, just format the data only on display mode and return raw data for the other modes.

Read Documentation here:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

You can see how your example works with this change:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  function loadHardware() {
    var results = {
      "profRigHardware": [{
          "title": "Product1",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product1/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product1.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "165.99",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product2",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product2/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product2.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "161.99",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product3",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product3/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product3.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-6.06",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product4",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-19.2",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product5",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product4/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product4.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-116.06",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product6",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-0.06",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product7",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "-18.24",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product8",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "75.68",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product9",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "863.31",
        },
        {
          "title": "Product10",
          "permalink": "http://test.com/computer-hardware/product5/",
          "smallImg": "http://test.com/content/uploads/2018/07/product5.jpg",
          "daily_netProfit": "20.1",
        }
      ]
    };
    const rentabilityHtml = function(daily_netProfit) {
      if (daily_netProfit < 0) {
        return `<div style="color:red;"><b>$${daily_netProfit}/day</b></div>`
      } else {
        return `<div style="color:green;"><b>$${daily_netProfit}/day</b></div>`
      }
    }
    //transform data set
    let dataSet = results.profRigHardware.map((item, i) => [
      `<img src="${ item.smallImg }" alt="${ item.title }" height="42" width="42"> 
         <a href="${item.permalink}" target="_blank">
            ${item.title}
             </a>`,
      parseFloat(item.daily_netProfit),
    ])

    $('#allHardwareOverview').DataTable({
      data: dataSet,
      destroy: true,
      iDisplayLength: 25,
      responsive: true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "order": [
        [1, 'desc']
      ],
      columns: [{
          title: "Model"
        },
        {
          title: "Profitability",
          render: function(profit, type) {
            if (type == "display")
                return rentabilityHtml(parseFloat(profit))
            else
                return profit;
          }
        }
      ],
      "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $('#datatablediv').css('opacity', 1);
      }
    });
  }
  loadHardware();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
  <div class="table-responsive overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="allHardwareOverview" style="width:100%; float: left;" class="table table-bordered"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above seems to be the best answer, however if you want to quickly test this, you can try it by removing the $ in the profitability by doing

```js
profit.split('$');
//this returns an array ['','x.xx']
parseFloat(parsed[1]).toFixed(2)
```