# Sorting dates in DataTables? (function override)

Tags: javascript, datatables, overriding

DataTables properly sort dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format only. All other formats they sort as `string`.

As far as I'm not a fan of adding a library / plugin for every functionality into my projects I tried to solve it by myself.

DataTables are using `Date.parse()` function to "understand" the date and sort it. (according to https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18).
So I decided to override that function and modify it in the way it will "understand" also other date formats.

I added this JS into my code:

```
            let origFunction = Date.parse;

            Date.parse = function(str) {

                // I want to parse this date format: 27.01.2018
                if (str.indexOf('.') > 0) {
                    str = convertDateToISO(str); // my function translates date into 2018-01-27
                }
                return origFunction(str);
            };
```

When I test this in the browser console, `Date.parse` works perfectly fine with my date format, but DataTables keep sorting my european dates as strings.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is it possible to do it this way?

**SOLVED:**

After all it looks like really the easiest way is to include "Moment.js" plugin as described here: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18#Operation
But while there was a "no plugin" requirement in my question, I'm accepting answer of @billynoah as a solution too.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146427/datetime-plugin-doesnt-sort-in-datatable/53146822#53146822. I made an answer there of how to use the `type` argument when rendering a column data.

Comment: Hmmm I just included Moment.js from the CDN as written in article I have linked, then I added one new line into my code: `$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');` and that was it. It works like a charm. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Yea, I know, but it is another alternative when you don't want to use `Moment` or when you, for example, render icons on the column and need to made some ordering on they.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [orthogonal-data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).  This allows you to define a custom value for sorting your column.  In this case, the most straightforward thing to do is use a timestamp for sorting and then you can display date in any format you want.  For data sourced from an object or ajax you can structure your column definition like:

```
{
    data: 'date',
    render: {
        _: 'display',
        sort: 'timestamp'
    }
}
```

For html source you can use the `data-order` attribute:

```
<td data-order="1545466488">Sat, Dec 22nd 2018</td>
```

*(Disclaimer / Attribution: This is all more or less straight out of the manual linked above)*

Comment: Thanks, but anyway... I'm curious why overriding `Date.parse` doesn't work :)

Comment: I haven't really dug into the source to have enough context to comment on that.  I figure they've already provided a convenient way to accomplish custom sorting and doing modifications to the source seems like a treacherous direction.  That said, it's always good to seek a better understanding when things don't work the way you'd expect.

Comment: I really like Datatables though and they've done a lot to improve and build on the project over the years.  cheers and good luck with your project